# how to avoid refresh each cell data on scroll in tableview ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have tableView with custom cell. I load some information from the web services and add it to the table if user scroll table down. Problem: after loading information in cells data change while scrolling. There is my code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if(indexPath.section == ProductDetailSectionId.ProductDetailView.rawValue) {
        if(self.productDetailModel != nil){
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "type1", for: indexPath) as? ProductDetailViewCell {
                cell.delegate = self
                cell.configureProductDetail(model: self.productDetailModel!)
                return cell
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What data changes you get when you scroll, is there duplication?

Comment: Write better code to set any UI element to a defined state for example by adding `else` clauses. By the way your code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reuse cells you can do it like this :

```
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "CellReuseIdentifier")
```

However this is very bad practice and will lead to crashes depending on how big the data used

if i were you i'd just maintain the current way but make sure on setting the data on cell on completion of download that it's the right cell

Comment: This immediately causes a crash, "Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell'". It doesn't address the IndexPath.

Comment: cast it to the cell type you have like this:

Comment: let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "CellReuseIdentifier") as? YourCellClass

Comment: My answer was meant for making cells not reusable not about creating a specific cell